# How do I SWIPE through ViewControllers using Storyboard ID

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, storyboard, swipe

Hello guys im noob in programming and im building an app but Im stuck on a part when i need to swipe through my viewcontroillers

I already build them in mainstoryboard and now I need to swipe left and right 
I read on articles that it can be done using storyboard ID so if someone can just give me a simple example of code how to swipe left and right on 2 random view controlers using SWIFT

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use for it UIPageViewController. 
You can find some examples  here:

- [UIPageViewController in Swift - Xcode 6.2 iOS 8.2 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ)
- [An Example Swift iOS 8 UIPageViewController Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_UIPageViewController_Application)

Comment: Thank you for your answear i think that will do the job